# Свои функции в программе glut/OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glut

Разбираюсь в OpenGL. Создала при помощи glut окошко и там рисую. Все было нормально, пока не решила вынести рисование параллелограмма в отдельную функцию. Вызываю ее первый раз - все работает как надо, второй раз - не рисует. В чем тут хитрость?

Функция представляет собой просто ряд следующих блоков:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex3f(0 + x, 0 + y, w / 2 + z);
glVertex3f(0 + x, h + y, w / 2 + z);
glVertex3f(l + x , h + y, w / 2 + z);
glVertex3f(l + x , 0 + y, w / 2 + z);
glEnd();
```

Вызов в цикле:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    draw_plate(200, 5, 20, -350 + 20 * i, -126, 0);
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Rendering Context не установлен? (мало кода в вопросе)

Comment: В вопросе недостаточно информации, чтобы дать однозначный ответ